# HTML elements to fill the widths of their table cells, but with a small & consistent bit of padding around

Tags: html, css, width, margin, padding

Answered my own question.  Here is the answer:

```
table, th, td  { border:1px solid black; padding-left:4px; padding-right:4px; }
input[type="text"], button, select
               { width: 100%;
                 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                 -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
                 box-sizing:         border-box; }
```

---

In my webpage (source code below), several elements do not fill the widths of their table cells: the input text fields, the grade selects, and the Insert button. My desired result is that  ***I would like each to fill the width of its table cell, but with a small bit of padding around it, as the Delete button has around it.***

I have tried various combinations of CSS styles, including 'width:100%', 'padding:2px', plus others.  However, I have have not been able to obtain the combination to yield the desired result. Might anyone know how I can achieve my desired result?

I am using Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m, and my HTML source code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Presidential Grade</title>
    <style>
      table, th, td  { border:1px solid black; }
      fieldset       { border-style:solid; border-color:red; display:inline-block; }
      legend         { font-style:italic; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; }
      select         { font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div>
        <fieldset>
          <legend>&nbsp;Presidential Grade&nbsp;</legend>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Action</th>
              <th>
                &nbsp;Last Name<span style='color:green;'>&nbsp;&utrif;&nbsp;</span>
              </th>
              <th>&nbsp;First Name&nbsp;</th>
              <th>
                &nbsp;Grade<span style='color:green;'>&nbsp;&utrif;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><button>Delete</button></td>
              <td>
                <input type='text' maxlength='20' size='7' value='Adams'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type='text' maxlength='20' size='7' value='John'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value='A'>A</option>
                  <option value='B'>B</option>
                  <option value='C'>C</option>
                  <option value='D'>D</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style='background-color:#D0FFD0;'>
              <td><button>Insert</button></td>
              <td style='display:none;'></td>
              <td>
                <input type='text' style='color:DarkBlue;' maxlength='20' size='7'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type='text' style='color:DarkBlue;' maxlength='20' size='7'>
              </td>
              <td>
                <select>
                  <option value='A'>A</option>
                  <option value='B'>B</option>
                  <option value='C'>C</option>
                  <option value='D'>D</option>
                </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any element that is a direct child of a TD, make 100 percent wide:

```
td > * {width: 100%;}
```

And to add some padding:

```
td {padding: 8px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6nBG8/

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and, I'm sorry, but it still does not look quite right to me.

Comment: You wanted the elements to expand and have padding.  They do in the example.   I guess you stated your requirements incorrectly.